# PHP error reporting: line number AND relevant line of code?

Tags: php, error-reporting

I'm attempting to write all of my PHP errors to a log file.  I'm interested in including not just the line number, but also the specific line of code associated with that line number.  This is the code I have so far.  What would I have to add/change in order to report the problematic lines of code?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('html_errors', 1);
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "./php-error.log");
```

Comment: [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) & [`error_get_last()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php)

Comment: I'm not sure how I would integrate those with the log's output.  I tried adding "error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));", but that just gave a blank array.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Look more into error_get_last().

Comment: I've looked into the documentation and tried adding it to my code, but I'm still not seeing how I can get it to report the actual line of code that's throwing the notice (I'm mainly dealing with undefined constant/variable issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to automatically print the line of code. You can however get the file and line number using `debug_backtrace()`. Then you can read the file yourself and find the right line and print it.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  That's good to know, so I don't go off on a wild goose chase. :) The script I have already prints the line number, so I'll just copy-paste the code into Excel to find the problematic string of code.